# Tipo primitivo int() no Python

Tags: python, tipagem, int

Sou **iniciante**(*1 semestre de TADS*), o máximo de programação que vi foi *lógica de programação* e agora comecei a estudar *Python*.

No curso de Python do [Curso em Vídeo](https://www.cursoemvideo.com/course/curso-python-3/) ele ensinou que o tipo primitivo **int()** deve ser escrito como:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um valor: '))
n2 = int(input('Digite outro valor: '))
s = n1 + n2
print(s)
```

No mesmo dia vi uma solução que escrevia de outra forma, assim:

```
n1 = input('Digite um valor: ')
n2 = input('Digite outro valor: ')
s = int(n1) + int(n2)
print(s)
```

Alguma entre as duas pode dar algum tipo de erro futuramente ou posso usar a que bem entender?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As duas formas são perfeitamente equivalentes quando considerado apenas o resultado produzido, mas a legibilidade do código difere. A saber, a função nativa `input` sempre retorna um valor do tipo *string*, mesmo se digitado um número. Na primeira forma, fica explícito já nas primeiras linhas que o desejado é trabalhar com valores inteiros e, desta forma, tanto `n1` quanto `n2` recebem o retorno de `input` convertido para inteiros. Já no segundo caso, ambos os objetos serão do tipo *string* e, visto que o objetivo é somar dois números, não faz muito sentido armazená-los como tal. Em outras palavras, o primeiro trecho de código traduz perfeitamente qual é a intenção do programa, enquanto o segundo não.

> Vale lembrar que `int` no Python é uma classe nativa e que quando chamado `int()` não está invocando uma função com este nome, mas sim o método inicializador da classe `int`. Isto é, você está instanciando a classe passando o respectivo valor para o inicializador.

**Qual utilizar?**

De modo bem geral, eu preferiria utilizar a primeira variação, dado o que comentei anteriormente, mas isso não implica que a segunda forma esteja errada. Dependendo da situação, a segunda pode fazer mais sentido: a citar, um problema onde você, necessariamente, irá precisar armazenar os valores como *strings*.

Comment: Obrigado, excelente resposta!

Answer (score 6):

Se alguém disse que o tipo `int` deve ser escrito assim já está ensinando errado. A função `int()` serve para converter algum valor de outro tipo em um inteiro, se for possível.

Nenhum dos dois tem problemas, é a mesma coisa. É igual matemática, escrever a mesma fórmula de forma diferente não muda o resultado. Mas eu faria de uma forma diferente.

Para um iniciante a segunda forma parece ser a mais fácil de entender. Ela está pegando dois valores digitados pelo usuário e depois está convertendo cada um deles em inteiro para somar. Ela está conceitualmente errada se considerar que `n1` e `n2` parecem querer guardar números, e está guardando textos. mas não muda o resultado. Eu gosto do conceitualmente certo porque ele te leva para o caminho certo.

A primeira forma também dá para entender bem e de certa forma pode até ser mais fácil de entender. Ela está mais correta no meu ponto de vista porque `n1` e `n2` já guarda números porque a conversão é feita logo após a entrada do dado.

Poderia evitar variáveis:

```
print(int(input('Digite um valor: ') + int(input('Digite outro valor: '))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/ToInt.py).

Comment: Obrigado!


Não deixei mais informações na pergunta por tanto o erro foi meu: O professor do curso, Gustavo Guanabara, não impôs um modo único de escrever, na verdade ele nem mostrou a outra maneira, descobri por conta própria respondendo um exercício. Por tanto, o que ele fez foi mostrar uma forma da solução, mas não estava em suas intenções delimitar somente aquilo.


Alias, ótima resposta!